# Is it possible to copy a directory from a Google Compute Engine instance to my local machine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

With scp I can add the `-r` flag to download directories to my local machine via ssh.

When using:

```
gcloud compute scp -r
```

it sais that '-r' is not an available option. 
Without -r I get an error saying that my source path is a directory. (Implying I can only download single files.)

Is there an equivalent to `-r` flag for `gcloud compute scp` command?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Found it!**

GCE offers an equivalent and it is `--recurse`.

My final command looks like this:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse username@instance_name:./* "local_dir"
```

For some reason I also needed the `*` behind the source folder to avoid some security issue.

Comment: make sure not to have a space after the `instance_name:`, that got me for a few minutes...

Comment: I have an app engine. I open the cloud shell. I want to copy a file from the cloud shell to my local machine. Any idea on how to do this? Since I dont have a VM

Comment: @james Did you figure out how to do this for app engine?

Comment: @frank yes i did

Comment: @james Oops, I meant "can you post the exact command so the community has it here?"

Comment: @frank I used above command. e.g. gcloud compute scp --recurse <remotecomputer_vm> ./* <mycomputer>.
here is another example
# Copy all files and directories recursively from server to the current system's /tmp folder.
scp -r server:/var/www /tmp

Answer (score 0):

Your gutils already has the right credentials, so just simply do

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse [the_instance_name]:[the_path_on_gcp_instance_folder] [the_path_on_your_machine]
```