# Error using gcloud compute scp with Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, scp, google-cloud-build

I've been trying to run a `gcloud compute scp` command using Google Cloud Build trigger. I want my code to be copied to the respective directories in listed servers.

However, it's kinda strange that when I do a `gcloud compute scp * username@instance-name:/home/directory --zone=us-central1-a --recurse` in Cloud Shell, it works.

But when I write the equivalent in the `cloudbuild.yaml` file, it fails with error: `*: No such file or directory`.

Here are the contents for my `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['compute' , 'scp' , '*', 'username@instance-name:/home/directory' , '--zone=us-central1-a', '--recurse']
```

I've also tried using the [remote-builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder) and that fails as well with error:

```
ssh: connect to host <ip_address> port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

I've also tried other combinations by replacing the source `*` with `/workspace/*`, `./*` etc. but none of them worked. Executing with source as `/workspace/` works but that copies the entire `workspace` directory instead of the contents of the directory as desired.

I've tried running the following set as well but that failed too.

`cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
- name: 'ubuntu'
  args: ['bash', '-c' , 'scp', '*', 'username@instance-name:/home/directory']
```

Error:

```
Already have image: ubuntu
scp: command not found
```

Again, all I want is to use Cloud Build to copy my code over to the VMs. Please help.

Comment: I suspect a couple of things. First, you'll need to grant Cloud Build's service account permission to your VMs. Second, Cloud Shell authenticates as your personal Cloud credentials and these credentials likely have permission to the VMs. I've not tried it but, once Cloud Build's account has permission to the VM, I think you'll need to `scp` to `root@instance`.

Comment: In that case, replacing the source as `/workspace/` should've also not worked. I'm right now assuming that there's something here is going wrong when I want to copy the contents of the `workspace` mount by stating the source something like `/workspace/*`

Comment: Hey Pranay... Are you able to SSH normally (Without cloud shell); if not you might need a way to get those keys across .. Chk this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204216/problem-with-data-transfer-from-cloud-build-container-to-google-compute-engine-i

Comment: Hey Dharmesh, yes that works. I'm able to copy files if I name them explicitly but not if I put an `*` in the source.

Answer (score 0):

**For the 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud' container image option:**

The asterisk, "*", is interpreted by `bash` and expanded before passing the referents to the command, and, as `gcloud` in this  container image is used directly and not through `bash` as an intermediary, "*" is not expanded, but passed literally to the `gcloud` command, which doesn't find any file named "*". If you need to copy all the code (directories recursively and their files) in the repository, use the same command but writing the root symbol, "/" (which, by the way, is a literal -not expandable- to `bash`), instead of "*".

**For the OS container image option with bash:**

The container image must have `scp` installed by default to work that way, and the "ubuntu" image doesn't have it by default. You could either use an image with the `openssh-client` package installed by default, or install it in place and then run the command, something like this (for the step syntax, check [this](https://medium.com/@davidstanke/mastering-google-cloud-build-config-syntax-8c3024607daf)):

```
steps:
- name: 'ubuntu'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    sudo apt update && sudo apt install openssh-client -y && scp * username@instance-name:/home/directory
```

Comment: I had kinda guessed that interpreting '*' could be a reason for the `'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'` container. I tried what you suggested but sorry, didn't work. This is what I tried:
`- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['compute',  'scp', '/', 'username@instance-name:/home/directory', '--zone=us-central1-a', '--recurse']`. I also tried this and it did not work either: 
`- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['gcloud', 'compute',  'scp', '*', 'username@instance-name:/home/directory', '--zone=us-central1-a', '--recurse']`

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm getting by using 
`- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
   entrypoint: 'bash'
   args: 
   - '-c'
   -  |
       for d in *; do
        gcloud compute scp $d username@instance-name:/home/directory --zone=us-central1-a --recurse
       done`

Comment: Do you mean you tried using "/" instead of "*"? The things you show you tried are not what I suggested: The name of the step needs to be 'ubuntu' (or 'debian', etc.).

Comment: Oh, my bad. I tried using this: `- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud' args: ['compute', 'scp', '/', 'username@instance-name:/home/directory', '--zone=us-central1-a', '--recurse']` Is it wrong? Should it be the following instead? `- name: 'ubuntu' args: ['gcloud', 'compute', 'scp', '/', 'username@instance-name:/home/directory', '--zone=us-central1-a', '--recurse']`

Comment: Have you tried `steps:  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud' entrypoint: 'bash' args: ['gcloud' 'compute' , 'scp' , '*', 'username@instance-name:/home/directory' , '--zone=us-central1-a', '--recurse']`?

Comment: @EmilGi, that's what I did. It's ```steps:  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud' entrypoint: 'bash' args: - '-c' - | for d in *; do gcloud compute scp  '*' username@instance-name:/home/directory --zone=us-central1-a' done```. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I have ended up creating two steps instead:

```
  - name: 'google/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - compute
      - scp
      - '--recurse'
      - '--compress'
      - /workspace/dist
      - 'build@instance-1:/var/www/'
      - '--zone'
      - us-west2-a
    id: copy-file-to-server
    entrypoint: gcloud
  - name: 'google/cloud-sdk:slim'
    args:
      - compute
      - ssh
      - '--zone'
      - us-west2-a
      - build@instance-1
      - '--'
      - 'mv /var/www/dist /var/www/$_SHORT_SHA '
    id: rename-dist
    entrypoint: gcloud
```